What is the best way to handle multiple logins for MS Outlook and MS Teams?
As a freelancer, I have multiple login for both Outlook and Teams. I have my own account, plus corporate logins with a few different clients.
Switching accounts, either on desktop or mobile phone, is always frustrating. It's seemingly impossible to logout of one account, and login into another, without going through some poorly defined sequence.
The most common thing to run into is that, if you logout, when you try to login in again, it insists that the only account which exists, is the one you just logged out from.
Is there a surefire way to actually log out of an account, and then re-login "fresh" ?
This is using the browser version of each product, from Chromium on Linux.

yeah this is a wide-spread problem, and basically it comes down to browsers being ill-fit to handle the idea that you might have multiple identities for the same service. one thing you can try with Chrome is to use different "Profiles". https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2364824?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop . haven't tried it myself, but it should be easier to maintain than Incognito. Another option is to use different browsers for different identities. that has the advantage of allowing you to have windows from multiple identities open at the same time.

If you're accessing via web browser, have you tried simply accessing them using an Incognito mode copy of the browser?
Once finished simply close the browser, open another in Incognito and it shouldn't retain the information about the previous login.
If it asks you if you want "Stay signed in?" you can say yes, as that is only applied during the incognito browser session, and prevents you getting re-prompted for details while using the current account.
Not had to do that with Teams fortunately, but accessing 365 admin for various customers with different login details needs this.

Yes, you can sign in to the web version of Teams or Outlook in private mode to avoid automatically caching passwords.
On the other hand, you can go to the browser to manually delete the cached password, and you will need to log in again the next time you log in. Go to your browser privacy settings and delete caches, cookies, etc.

By "private mode", do you mean "incognito". That seems to be what it's called in Firefox.

Yeah that's right @Stewart, Chrome/Chromium = Incognito, Firefox = Private, Edge = InPrivate. Different names in each browser but the same thing. So since in your question you stated Chromium I opted to specify that one in my answer. :)
